# How to get Google Chrome Browser Source Code?

Tags: google-chrome, open-source

I have tried a variety of websites for how to get Google Chrome Browser Source Code: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Is there a good, (a bit clearer), video or article on how to simply download the Google Chrome code, and be able to totally edit it, on my computer, without all the depot tools etc?

What is the need for the depot_tools and/or cygwin etc?

Comment: If you hadn't given the link, the answer would have been to go to that link. Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @GregHewgill
Just all the confusion of depot_tools, prerequisites, cygwin, command line, when i find all I should do is just click "download" and get it.

Comment: You still need the build tools and prerequisites to actually build it.

Comment: Your curiosity in the source code is good, but I feel that I must tell you this: If your having difficulty with the instructions on that page, it's not going to get easier once you have the source. It might be a good idea to learn how to program on a Linux platform and build your way up to working on a project like Chrome.

Comment: I have the code now, and shall open it, thanks for that @aganders3 but what will I now need to build and Test? Thanks.

Comment: To proceed to *building*, look on the same how-to page where you found the "how to get the code" page. There are links to "build instructions" for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: Every time you call Chromium "Chrome", a kitten dies.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to to get it, try this [link](http://chromium-browser-source.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome_android.v18.0.1025123.tgz) (warning: it's a 256 MB file).
This is an archive that you can extract once it's on your computer (use e.g. tar or 7zip or some other decompression software).

> What is the need for the depot_tools and/or cygwin etc?

These tools will allow you to keep the source code on your computer up to date without downloading a full 256 MB file every time. This is helpful because many open source projects are updated very frequently, and you don't want to download 256 MB every day (or hour) when it's really only (relatively) small changes you need to get.

---

The main Chromium project is located at https://www.chromium.org/.

The source code is available at https://chromium.googlesource.com/ and can be searched at https://cs.chromium.org/.

Instructions for contributing can be found at https://www.chromium.org/developers.

Comment: That is chromium, which isn't exactly chrome. Is the source code of Chrome available? If not, shouldn't it be, given the license of devkit? ditto for Safari.

Comment: @Uri - you are correct! Unfortunately the Chrome source is not open. The licensing seems complicated (and I am not a lawyer), but it appears the open source components (including WebKit) mainly use a BSD license. This is not a "copyleft" license, so I think Google (and Apple) don't need to open the proprietary code they add to make Chrome and Safari.